# Thread local storage vs. repeat string instructions (rep movs)

Tags: multithreading, thread-local-storage, rep

I wonder how compilers (GCC or LLVM as example) behave when a variable is declared to be stored in Thread Local Storage (TLS) but the code with the variable is a candidate for generating repeat string instruction (rep movsd, rep stos and etc). I guess that as rep string instructions store data in ES segment, they are suppressed by a compiler to be generated for TLS variables. But it is just my assumption. If you know an exact answer, welcome.

Thanks,
Andrei.

Comment: I do not understand anything of your question. What is the relationship between SSL/TLS and compilers?

Comment: Here TLS stands for Thread Local Storage, not the security related stuff.

Comment: As always for these simple questions: Just check for whatever compiler that interests you.

Comment: I tried to write an example of C-code to make GCC compiler generate repeat string instructions. Unlucky. Any ideas?

Comment: Ok, @GireeshPunathil, then the tag ssl is incorrect. andrei, please edit the question so I could retract my vote